# How to see at what time does each python operation runs?

Tags: python, time

I'm new to Python. I'm working on a script on Python3 which sends different requests and I want to see at what time does each request is being sent and it got shown on my terminal. I tried looking into time docs but couldn't find what I am looking for. 
Hope it is clear

Thank you

Comment: check this: [Measure execution time of small code snippets¶](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the current time with:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
>>> import time
>>> print(time.asctime())
Mon Apr  2 15:45:42 2018
>>>
```